# Gmap3 markers visible, but can't interact with them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that uses Gmap3 and RichMarker and it works, for the most part. The only caveat is that you can't hover over or click the markers or clusters. I thought it was a simple CSS issue, but it's not. even when you hover over the marker, the cursor doesn't change as seen in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax3Cf.jpg.

The code for the marker starts at line 133 (or below the question) on: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d94d4476875cf58413b2#file-map-javascript-php-L133

I can't figure out why the cursor won't even change. Even on normal Google Maps, when you hover over a marker the cursor changes to a pointer. :/

```
,marker: {
    values: [
        {foreach $items as $item}
            {
                latLng: [{ifset $item->optionsDir['gpsLatitude']}{!$item->optionsDir['gpsLatitude']}{else}0{/ifset},{ifset $item->optionsDir['gpsLongitude']}{!$item->optionsDir['gpsLongitude']}{else}0{/ifset}],
                data: '<div class="marker-holder"><div class="marker-content{ifset $item->thumbnailDir} with-image"><a href="{!$item->link}"><img src="{thumbnailResize $item->thumbnailDir, w => 280, h => 160}" alt="">{else}">{/ifset}<div class="map-item-info"><div class="title">&#36;'+{ifset $item->optionsDir["price"]}{$item->optionsDir["price"]}+{/ifset}' <small>{!$item->rooms}bd/{!$item->baths}ba</small></div><div class="address">'+{ifset $item->optionsDir["address"]}{$item->optionsDir["address"]|nl2br}+{/ifset}',<br>'+{ifset $item->optionsDir["address2"]}{$item->optionsDir["address2"]|nl2br}+{/ifset}'</div><div class="timestamp">{!$item->time}</div></div></a><div class="arrow"></div><div class="close">x</div></div></div></div>'
            }
        {if !($iterator->last)},{/if}
        {/foreach}
    ],
    options:{
        draggable: false,
        content: "<div class='cluster-bg'><div class='cluster'><span>1</span></div></div>",
        width: 44,
        shadow: 0,
        height: 44
    },
    cluster:{
        radius: 100,
        // This style will be used for clusters with more than 0 markers
        0: {
            content: "<div class='cluster-bg'><div class='cluster cluster-1'><span>CLUSTER_COUNT</span></div></div>",
            width: 44,
            height: 44
        },
        events: {
            click: function(cluster) {
                map.panTo(cluster.main.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
            },
            mouseover: function(cluster) {
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('padding', '10px 10px');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('margin', '-4px 0 0 -4px');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster').css('background-color', '#343434');
            },
            mouseout: function(cluster) {
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('padding', '6px');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('margin', '0');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster-bg').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.15)');
                $(cluster.main.getDOMElement()).find('.cluster').css('background-color', 'rgba(85, 151, 183, 1.0)');
            }
        }
    },
    events: {
        click: function(marker, event, context){
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

            infobox.setContent(context.data);
            infobox.open(map,marker);

            // if map is small
            var iWidth = 260;
            var iHeight = 300;
            if((mapDiv.width() / 2) < iWidth ){
                var offsetX = iWidth - (mapDiv.width() / 2);
                map.panBy(offsetX,0);
            }
            if((mapDiv.height() / 2) < iHeight ){
                var offsetY = -(iHeight - (mapDiv.height() / 2));
                map.panBy(0,offsetY);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: So linking to a Gist isn't acceptable?

Comment: Since Gist != *code in the question itself*, no.  The reason is that if you decide to delete your gist code, this question becomes completely useless to future readers.

Comment: What does it say when you click? any errors? what if you add console.log inside click event?

Comment: What [version of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) are you using? The [issues list is reflecting a lot of issues similar to this in the experimental version.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=&sort=-modified)

Comment: @geocodezip, that's exactly what it was!

Comment: Please star the appropriate issue (or create a new one) so it gets fixed before this version becomes the "release" version... (not that I don't expect the Maps API team to notice all the complaints and fix it before then)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a common issue with the experimental version of the Gmaps API. The fix is to revert to a former version of the script by tagging `"v=3.16"` to the end of the url such as:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.16
```

All thanks goes to geocodezip for pointing out the similarity between my problem and many others'.